# Dynamically add property:value in JSON through rest services

Tags: java, json, rest, properties

How do we create a json property:value dynamically by taking them as inputs from the user through a REST service, without having to have fields to hold the value.

Basically, the present output is :

```
{
    "name": "X",
    "price": "X",
    "ticker": "X",
    "status": "X",
    "supplier": "X",
    "attribute": [{
            "key": "index",
            "value": "Nasdaq"
        },
        {
            "key": "priority",
            "value": "high"
        }
    ]
}
```

Required output is :

```
{
    "name": "X",
    "price": "X",
    "ticker": "X",
    "status": "X",
    "supplier": "X",
    "attribute": [{
            "index": "Nasdaq"
        },
        {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, index and Nasdaq are the values given by the user, which is the key-value pair that is to be added to the attribute list.

The two POJO's used :

Stock.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Stock {

    public Stock() {

    }

    public Stock(String name, double price, String ticker, String status, String supplier, List<KV> attribute) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.status = status;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String ticker;
    private String status;
    private String supplier;

    private List<KV> attribute;


    public List<KV> getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }


    public void setAttribute(List<KV> attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }

    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

}
```

And :
KV.java

```
public class KV {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public KV(String key, String value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Would prefer answers relating to usage of annotations or changes in the rest service, and not text processing at the end.

Comment: dont you think its irrelevant to have a structure like `"attribute": [{"index":"Nasdaq"}, {"priority":"high"}]`, If you are restructuring it, its better to have `"attribute": {"index":"Nasdaq", "priority":"high"}`

Comment: Basically needed it to be a list, each of those curly braces will have a lot more data grouped together in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, once you get the response you are getting currently then instead of a class "public class KV {} ", you can create a Hashmap,
& key of the Hashmap can hold the index/priority etc & value can hold Nasdaq/high.

Also name the Hashmap variable as "attribute".

So that you can extract the data from API using your current structure & then can convert it to one as I said above & send the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, implemented it through hashmap. But now I'm facing an issue where the getAttribute returns the value, but returns null when I return the object :

attributes=[{index=Nasdaq, priority=High}, {One=Two, Three=Four}]]

When returned :

"attributes":[null,null]

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Attributes** class in java
Instead of defining a list of object you can just define
**Attribute** attributes;

For more details about how Attribute class works visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html